# tic tac toe better way of finding the matched symbol and the winner?

Tags: c++

I'm a beginner in coding and this is the most complex code that I have created
I'ts a simple tic tac toe game and I'm asking if there's a better way of finding the matched X and O

```
string getWinner(string _gameBoard[ROW][COL]) // get the winner
{
    

    for (int i = 0; i < ROW; i++)
        {
            if (_gameBoard[i][0] != " " && _gameBoard[i][0] == _gameBoard[i][1] && _gameBoard[i][1] == _gameBoard[i][2])
                return _gameBoard[i][0]; //horizontal match
        }
    
        for (int j = 0; j < COL; j++)
        {
            if (_gameBoard[0][j] != " " && _gameBoard[0][j] == _gameBoard[1][j] && _gameBoard[1][j] == _gameBoard[2][j])
                return _gameBoard[0][j]; //vertical match
        }
    
        if (_gameBoard[0][0] != " " && _gameBoard[0][0] == _gameBoard[1][1] && _gameBoard[1][1] == _gameBoard[2][2])
            return _gameBoard[0][0]; // diagonal match // upper left to lower right
    
        if (_gameBoard[2][0] != " " && _gameBoard[2][0] == _gameBoard[1][1] && _gameBoard[1][1] == _gameBoard[0][2])
            return _gameBoard[2][0]; // diagonal match // upper lower left to upper right
    
        return "";
    }
```

Comment: It would not be that complex, if you had, for example, separate functions for checking a row, a column, a down diagonal and up diagonal. In each function you'd better use a cycle to check that values on `_gameBoard` are equal. With cycle you'll be able to easily make your game e.g. 5x5

Comment: For improvements on working code, you should try [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). If you decide to post there, consider deleting this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you better hold your `gameBoard` as 2D array of `char`, because `string` is heavy and unnecessary.

Next, as I suggested in the comment, you can split all the logic into separate functions like that. Don't be afraid that they return strange `std::pair<bool, char>` it's just a way of returning two values from a single function (technically it returns a single value, but it has one `bool` and one `char` packed inside). The boolean corresponds to whether a winner is found after check and the character corresponds to a character of winner, if there is some.

Inside each function you have a loop. This loop compares `i`'th element and `0`'th element. If you find once that they're not equal, then the whole row/col/diagonal is not equal, so we return there is no winner. If the function reaches the end, it means all values were equal, so there is a winner.

`getWinner` then just calls all the functions and decides who is finally a winner.

```
std::pair<bool, char> checkRow(char gameBoard[ROW][COL], int rowId) {
  for (int i = 1; i < COL; ++i) {
    if (gameBoard[rowId][i] != gameBoard[rowId][0]) {
      return std::make_pair(false, ' '); // false indicates no winner on this row 
    }
  }
  return std::make_pair(true, gameBoard[rowId][0]); // true indicates there is a winner
}

std::pair<bool, char> checkCol(char gameBoard[ROW][COL], int colId) {
  for (int i = 1; i < ROW; ++i) {
    if (gameBoard[colId][i] != gameBoard[colId][0]) {
      return std::make_pair(false, ' '); // false indicates no winner on this col 
    }
  }
  return std::make_pair(true, gameBoard[colId][0]); // true indicates there is a winner
}

std::pair<bool, char> checkDownDiagonal(char gameBoard[ROW][COL]) {
  for (int i = 1; i < COL; ++i) {
    if (gameBoard[i][i] != gameBoard[0][0]) {
      return std::make_pair(false, ' '); // false indicates no winner on this diagonal 
    }
  }
  return std::make_pair(true, gameBoard[0][0]); // true indicates there is a winner
}

std::pair<bool, char> checkUpDiagonal(char gameBoard[ROW][COL]) {
  for (int i = 1; i < COL; ++i) {
    if (gameBoard[ROW-1-i][i] != gameBoard[ROW-1][0]) {
      return std::make_pair(false, ' '); // false indicates no winner on this diagonal 
    }
  }
  return std::make_pair(true, gameBoard[0][0]); // true indicates there is a winner
}

std::pair<bool, char> getWinner(char gameBoard[ROW][COL]) {
  auto downDiag = checkDownDiagonal(gameBoard);
  if (downDiag.first) return downDiag; // `first` is flag if there's a winner
  
  auto upDiag = checkUpDiagonal(gameBoard);
  if (upDiag.first) return upDiag;
  
  for(int i = 0; i < ROW; ++i) {
    auto rowCheck = checkRow(gameBoard, i);
    if (rowCheck.first) return rowCheck;
  }

  for(int i = 0; i < COL; ++i) {
    auto colCheck = checkRow(gameBoard, i);
    if (colCheck.first) return colCheck;
  }
  return std::make_pair(false, ' ');
}
```

Comment: Instead of the `pair` the function can simply return `char`, with `' '` meaning no match. After all, all of the `pair` objects that hold `false` also hold `' '`, and none of the `pair` objects that hold `true` holds `' '`.

Comment: @PeteBecker unless you use `' '` instead of `'X'`, though yes it's unlikely, but returning of "invalid" value is an antipattern

Comment: Sigh. Yes, you have to pick the return value so that it doesn't conflict with the X and O representations. That's not at all hard, and it's simply part of **designing** the code. As is not providing redundant information in overly complex formats, which is the only antipattern here.